# How to write an SQL query generating a history of the sums of a column at different timestamps?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In a table, I have events showing values (`x`) for things with different IDs at different event timestamps.

```
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT 1 AS thing_id, 1 AS x, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:00:00') AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:01:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:02:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:03:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 0, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:04:00'))
SELECT
  * FROM events
```

```
+----------+---+---------------------+
| thing_id | x |   event_timestamp   |
+----------+---+---------------------+
|        1 | 1 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 |
|        1 | 3 | 2021-12-01 00:01:00 |
|        2 | 5 | 2021-12-01 00:02:00 |
|        1 | 2 | 2021-12-01 00:03:00 |
|        1 | 0 | 2021-12-01 00:04:00 |
+----------+---+---------------------+
```

I'd like to obtain a history showing the sum of all current `x` values for each known `event_timestamp`.

```
+---------------------+-------+
|   state_timestamp   | x_sum |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2021-12-01 00:00:00 |     1 |
| 2021-12-01 00:01:00 |     3 |
| 2021-12-01 00:02:00 |     8 |
| 2021-12-01 00:03:00 |     7 |
| 2021-12-01 00:04:00 |     5 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

What would the needed SQL statement look like? I'm trying to think about grouping per `thing_id`, windowing, and maybe cross joining on all `event_timestamp`s, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of `thing_id` ?
 If it's the case you can achieve the result with the `pivot` operator

Comment: @Cylldby No, the set of `thing_id`s is not known beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select event_timestamp, sum(ifnull(coalesce(x, prev_x), 0)) x_sum
from (
  select *, 
    first_value(x ignore nulls) over(partition by thing_id order by event_timestamp desc rows between 1 following and unbounded following) prev_x
  from (
    select *
    from (select distinct thing_id from events)
    cross join (select distinct event_timestamp from events)
    left join events using (event_timestamp, thing_id)
  )
)
group by event_timestamp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is so much better than [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789615/1866775), thank you! I'm now working on understanding it completely, such that I'd be able to write it on my own instead of just copying it. :)

Comment: While applying your nice/short solution to my actual data, I noticed that it [does not work as expected](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/019ae4ec19afd1b0aa92bb0be3113d8d). I adjusted my initial question to include the problematic case too.

Comment: confirming! looking into it now ...

Comment: Updated my answer. did not have chance to test much, so please check it again and let me know

Comment: Very nice! Now, the results on my real data are the same as with my long/ugly solution. Thanks a lot again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Having found explanations of the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, I think I managed to write a solution. It works fine with the given minimal example, but I'm not 100% sure if it works perfectly in general. (And I guess it can be simplified.)

```sql
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT 1 AS thing_id, 1 AS x, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:00:00') AS event_timestamp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:01:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:02:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:03:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 0, TIMESTAMP('2021-12-01 00:04:00')
),
  state_timestamps AS (
  SELECT
    event_timestamp state_timestamp
  FROM
    events),
  states AS (
  SELECT
    thing_id,
    state_timestamp,
    event_timestamp,
    x
  FROM
    events
  CROSS JOIN
    state_timestamps
  WHERE
    event_timestamp <= state_timestamp ),
  latest_states AS (
  SELECT
    a.thing_id,
    a.state_timestamp,
    a.event_timestamp,
    a.x
  FROM
    states a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      thing_id,
      state_timestamp,
      MAX(event_timestamp) event_timestamp
    FROM
      states
    GROUP BY
      thing_id,
      state_timestamp ) b
  ON
    a.thing_id = b.thing_id
    AND a.event_timestamp = b.event_timestamp
    AND a.state_timestamp = b.state_timestamp),
  sum_states AS (
  SELECT
    state_timestamp,
    SUM(x) x_sum
  FROM
    latest_states
  GROUP BY
    state_timestamp
  ORDER BY
    state_timestamp)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sum_states
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+-------+
|   state_timestamp   | x_sum |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2021-12-01 00:00:00 |     1 |
| 2021-12-01 00:01:00 |     3 |
| 2021-12-01 00:02:00 |     8 |
| 2021-12-01 00:03:00 |     7 |
| 2021-12-01 00:04:00 |     5 |
+---------------------+-------+
```